# Replace value with two arrays numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need your help in order to get a solution with my script.

I have 2 arrays :

==> The first one get 1 column which is named `code_client`. We will call the file : `excel.txt`.
==> The second one has 2 columns : `rowid`and `code_client`. We will call the file : `BDD.txt`.

I would like to replace in the first file the value by rowid associated with the second file.

First file looks like :

```
code_client
208
1643
1595
2607
2608
2470
1547
481
226
558
```

Second file looks like :

```
rowid,code_client
1,1
2,2
3,4
4,5
5,6
6,7
7,8
8,9
9,10
10,11
11,12
12,13
13,14
14,15
```

This is my script :

```
# Script permettant de remplacer le code_client par le rowid de la BDD

# coding: utf8

import numpy as np

# Importation du fichier excel

excel = np.loadtxt('/Users/valentinjungbluth/Desktop/excel.txt',
                    dtype = int)

#print excel

BDD = np.genfromtxt('/Users/valentinjungbluth/Desktop/BDD.txt',
                    dtype = [('rowid','i8'),('code_client','i8')],
                    delimiter = ',')

for row1 in excel :
    if excel == BDD['code_client'] :
        print 'oui'
    else :
        print 'non'
```

I don't know how I can associate values. I think I have to read rows from the `excel file` and compare with the `BDD file`. If I get the same number between `code_client from excel file` with `BDD file`, I replace `code_client` from `excel file` by `rowid` from `BDD.file`. Else I continue.

Is it possible to get some help ?

Thank you !

EDIT : EXPECTED FILE

The first file have to become :

```
code_client ==> rowid
208 ==> this code_client in the second file gives rowid = 183
1643 ==> this code_client in the second file gives rowid = 1498
1595 ==> ...
2607
2608
2470
1547
481
226
558
```

Comment: You have the row id, you have a `list` of rows in the first file, isn't the `row_id` the same as `index + 1`, you can just call `list[row_id - 1] = new_value`

Comment: What's the expected output for the sample?

Comment: @btquanto No because the first file is not order by ascendant value. I need to keep this order. Furthermore, rowid = 1,2,3 ... and code_client = 1,2,4 etc .. At the end rowid = 2800 and code_client = 3600

Comment: It does not matter if it's in ascending, descending or random order. check my answer

Comment: @Divakar : I added an EDIT part with the output expected ;)

Comment: I'll delete the answer, it doesn't seem to be what you want.

Comment: Please add the format of your `BDD` and `excel`

Comment: It's juste int values ^^ I just want to make the correspondance between the first file and the second file. On the paper, I arrive to materialize my idea, but I don't arrive to write the script to do that.

Comment: I updated the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what numpy does, but I guess here's what you want

```
dictionary = dict()
for data in BDD:
    # We are building a dictionary to associate the code_client with rowid
    dictionary[data['code_client']] = data['rowid']
for code_client in excel:
    # From the code_client, you can get the rowid from the dictionary
    row_id = dictionary.get(code_client, None)
    print code_client, "=>", row_id # Do what you want
```

You can also build the `dictionary` like this:

```
dictionary = dict([(data['code_client'], data['row_id']) for data in BDD])
```

I'm assuming your `BDD` is a `list` of `dict`, with keys are `rowid` and `code_client`; and your `excel` is a list of values

Comment: Both files are a list of values. I will try your script

Comment: It doesn't work. Syntax error with the last line. I will see what doesn't work. To the output file, I juste need to get rowid values in place of code_client values ;)

Comment: Yep I will see dictionary lesson ;)

Comment: I guess some `code_client` do not exist in the `dictionary`, causing a crash, so try `dictionary.get(code_client, None)` instead